# django async if else use a thread or sync_to_async

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, async-await, django-channels

I don't know where the error is.

I am using Django ORM asynchronously.

```py
@database_sync_to_async
def filter_data(**kwargs):
    return FinishAnimateModel.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

```py
async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
    ...
    if data['msg']:
        print('in')
        model = await DB.Myself.filter_data(name__contains='')
        print('ok')
    else:
        print('else')
        model = await DB.Myself.filter_data(name__contains='')
        print(model, 'model')
```

#### In if log

```
in
ok
```

#### In else log

```
else
You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

I try to reverse if else.

```py
async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
    ...
    if not data['msg']:
        pass
    else:
        print('else')
        model = await DB.Myself.filter_data(name__contains='')
        print(model, 'model')
```

#### In else log

```
else
You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

Why?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it could be passed in the `if` part only because you didn't `print(model)` in there. If you do, then you should see the same problem.

However, I may not be able to answer the question you asked -- It's too little information.

All I can say is that the type returned by `filter()` is `QuerySet`, if you want to print it, you must convert it to `list` type.

Reference: [Retrieving specific objects with filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters)

So, maybe you can modify it like this:

```py
async def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
    ...
    if not data['msg']:
        print('in')
        model = list(await DB.Myself.filter_data(name__contains=''))
        print(model, 'ok')
    else:
        print('else')
        model = list(await DB.Myself.filter_data(name__contains=''))
        print(model, 'model')
```

Or

```py
@database_sync_to_async
def filter_data(**kwargs):
    return list(FinishAnimateModel.objects.filter(**kwargs))
```